# Upgraded Spring-boot-starter parent to 2.5.12 from 2.5.6. Some junit assertions are failing with NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, resilience4j, spring-boot-starter, spring-framework-beans

failing cases:
After upgrading to 2.5.12 from 2.5.6, Some junit tests for asserting DataIntegrityViolationException were failing with NullPointerException.

this is my pom.xml file. Do I need to upgrade any other dependency? I read it somewhere that i need to update spring-cloud.version to 2020.0.5, but it's not working

currently i'm suing spring-cloud.version - 2020.0.3 and resilience4j-springboot2 version as 1.7.1.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.12</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <ims.events.model.version>0.0.32</ims.events.model.version>
    <ims-commons.version>1.0.94</ims-commons.version>
    <jackson-modules-version>2.13.0</jackson-modules-version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <javax.interceptor>1.2.2</javax.interceptor>
    <jvm.options>-Xss3M</jvm.options>
    <kafka.version>2.7.1</kafka.version>
    <logback.contrib.version>0.1.5</logback.contrib.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
    <maven.chekstyle.version>3.0.0</maven.chekstyle.version>
    <mssql.version>9.2.0.jre8</mssql.version>
    <okhttp3.version>4.1.1</okhttp3.version>
    <store-iro-util.version>1.1.60</store-iro-util.version>
    <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
    <resilience4j-spring-boot2.version>1.7.1</resilience4j-spring-boot2.version>
    <!-- resilience4j-spring-boot2.version must be co ordinated manually with the spring.cloud-version -->
    <shedlock.jdbc.version>2.1.0</shedlock.jdbc.version>
    <shedlock.version>2.5.0</shedlock.version>
    <simple-spring-memcached.version>4.1.3</simple-spring-memcached.version>
  

    <spring.cloud-version>2020.0.3</spring.cloud-version>
    <spring-kafka-test.version>2.7.1</spring-kafka-test.version>
    <spring-kafka.version>2.7.1</spring-kafka.version>
    <spring-starter.version>3.4.1</spring-starter.version>

    <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.3.9</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
    <testcontainers-version>1.16.0</testcontainers-version>
    
    <wiremock.version>2.27.2</wiremock.version>
    <xmemcached.version>2.4.7</xmemcached.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.7.0</liquibase.version>
    <spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
    <features-planavro.version>0.0.15-RELEASE</features-planavro.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter.version>3.0.4</spring-cloud-starter.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker.version>2.0.2</spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker.version>
    <maven-release-plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven-release-plugin.version>
    <dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>1.4.10</dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>
    
  </properties>

 

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.interceptor}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.strati.ioc</groupId>
      <artifactId>strati-af-ccm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-starter.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
      <version>${resilience4j-spring-boot2.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-transactions</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${simple-spring-memcached.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
      <version>${simple-spring-memcached.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.xmemcached</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmemcached</artifactId>
      <version>${xmemcached.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${mssql.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    

    


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
      <version>${shedlock.jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-modules-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-modules-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-mrbean</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-modules-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-modules-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing dependencies -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
      <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssqlserver</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-kafka-test.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>${kafka.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>${kafka.version}</version>
      <classifier>test</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>@{argLine} ${jvm.options}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.chekstyle.version}</version>
       
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>checkstyle/checkstyle.rules.xml</configLocation>
              <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
              <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <excludes>${checkstyle.excludes}</excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dockerdev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>unpack</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                      <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                  </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${dockerfile-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <repository>ims/${project.artifactId}</repository>
              <pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: `2.5.12` to `2.5.6` is a downgrade, you mean 2.6.x maybe ?

Comment: sorry for the wording, I upgraded from 2.5.6 to 2.5.12

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: With the version changed if you use SpringToolSuite4, forcing the Update Maven Project should work: Project > Update Maven Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Releases